# RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined

Tags: nodejs

Estoy tratando de actualizar la imagen de perfil que tengo en cloudinary, pero lo único que obtengo es un error que no tengo conocimiento (RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined)

**Este es mi código:**

```
exports.foto = catchAsyncError(async(req, res, err) => {
    
    let update = ''    
    const usuario = await Auth.findById(req.auth.id)
    const image_id = usuario.foto.public_id
    const eliminar = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(image_id)

    if(req.body.avatar !== ''){
        const usuario = await Auth.findById(req.auth.id)
        const image_id = usuario.foto.public_id
        const eliminar = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(image_id)

        const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
            folder: 'avatars',
            width: 150,
            crop: 'scale'
        })

        update.foto = {
            public_id: result.public_id,
            url: result.secure_url
        }
    }

    const photo = await Auth.findByIdAndUpdate(req.auth.id, update, {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
        useFindAndModify: false
    }) 

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        photo
    })      
})
```

---

**Error**:

> RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined
>     at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:259:11)
>     at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (*http_server.js:250:8)
>     at write* (_http_outgoing.js:711:9)
>     at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:825:5)
>     at ServerResponse.send(...)

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede ser que se genera un error no catcheado, entonces retorna el error y no la respuesta en el formato servidor web, tipo status(500), quizá en el router, deberías agregar algo como:

```
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{

    console.log(err)

    res.status(500).json({
        error : {
            message : err.message
       }
    });
})
```

Eso no va a solucionar el error original, pero va a redirigir los errores. En cuanto al código del status deberías hacer una discriminación del tipo de error.